# Why is $P(X \in D) \in ]0,1[$ not sufficient for $X$ to be a mixed variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $D$ be the set of discontinuity points of the distribution function associated to $X$. $D$ can be an empty set.

Why is $P(X \in D) \in ]0,1[$ not a sufficient condition for $X$ to be a mixed variable?

Comment: (1) What is a mixed random variable?  (2) Do you mean $0<P[X\in D]<1$?

Comment: @OliverDiaz https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Mixed_type

Comment: Just add the definition to you posting or put a reference. The Radon-Nijodym theorem shows that the distribution of $X$ can be decomposed as and absolutely continuous   measure (w.r.t. Lebesge's measure) and a singular measure (w.r.t. Lebesgue's measure). If the distribution of $X$ has no discontinuities, then $X$ is a continuous random  variable (it may still be singular w.r.t. Lebesgue's measure as the 1/3 Cantor measure shows), if $F$ has a jump discontinuity then $F$ has a non-trivial discrete part.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean... @OliverDiaz With the notation in this link, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_decomposition_theorem#Refinement , what are you trying to say? Thanks ;)

Comment: It suffices to look at the distribution function of $X$ (since presumably $X$ is real values) If $F$ is continuous, your random variable may be the mixture of an absolutely continuous random variable and a continuous one; if $F$ has a jump discontinuity, then $X$ then the discrete part (jump part) of the distribution of $X$ is non trivial. Then $X$ could be the mixture of  continuous random variable and a discrete one; or a purely discrete random variable. For example The Bernoulli random variable has distribution with jump discontinuities and it is purely discrete.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thanks. I know understood. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a discerte r.v. with induced measure $\sum a_i\delta_{x_i}$ the points of continuity are precisly the points ${x_i}$ and so $P(X \in D)=1$. For a continuous r.v. $D$ is empty set and $P (X \in D)=0$. Hence, the distribution is necessarily a mixture.